# How to display children name in D3 Treemap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I have created a tree map in D3 having parent and child relationship. I have colored the children based on their parents. I want to add children name as the text for each of the child rectangles.

Not sure how to access the child data in the 2 dimensional array.

[image]

Please find the details of my treemap in Github link below:
http://bl.ocks.org/geetanjalirana/4cdcfc2887ed93907225

I need to add the child text as highlighted in the example below.

For Instance:-

```
D = Children: Array[9]
    0: Object 1
    **Children: Array[10]**
      0: object 
      1: object 
      2: object
      ....
      9: object
```

How to access the children data which is in bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are appending the txt dom inside rect DOM which is wrong and the reason why text is not displayed.

In NewFile.js, inside function display(), line no 167:

```
var k = g.selectAll(".child")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.children || [d];
      })
      .enter();
   //append rectangle
    k.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "child")
      .call(rect);
    //append text
    k.append("text")
      .call(text);
```

And your function text like this:

```
function text(text) {
    text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 6; })
        .attr("dy", "1.80em")
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .style("text-anchor", "center")
        .attr("class","textdiv")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });//to display the name
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. I had tried this approach what happens here is it displays the first child name for each of the parent but not all child names. However, I need to display text for each child of the parent in the child rectangle. The problem here is that it has 9 parents and each parent has around more than 10 children and i need to text for each one of them. Using this approach it returns only 9 children text. I hope this makes it clear.  Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Hi All, 

I have made few modifications in the below treemap. I am able to create separate text elements for each of the child rectangles. However I am still unable to view the text against the rectangles. 

Please refer to the below link for details. 
http://bl.ocks.org/geetanjalirana/97c32fb8777f80d3f4ec

Kindly provide suggestions.

Regards

Comment: @GeetanjaliRana i have updated my answer based on your code

Comment: Hi, I tried to do so. Just let me know in case it didn't change anything.